# Moq Callback does not invoke moq that I've setup

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

My class and method that mocks:

```
public class EmailService: IEmailService
{
    private readonly ISendGridClient _client;

    public EmailService(ISendGridClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(string email, string senderAderess, string senderName, string recipientName, string subject, string content, string htmlContent)
    {
        var from = new EmailAddress(senderAderess, senderName);
        var to = new EmailAddress(email, recipientName);
        var plainContent = content;
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainContent, htmlContent);

        await _client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

And unit test for it

```
public async void EmailService_SendingEmail_EmailSentSuccessfullyAsync()
{
    var test = 0;

    var mockEmailClient = new Mock<ISendGridClient>();

    mockEmailClient.Setup(x => x.SendEmailAsync(new SendGridMessage(), CancellationToken.None)).Callback(() => test++);

    var emailSender = new EmailService(mockEmailClient.Object);

    await emailSender.SendAsync("mail@gmail.com", "SenderDemo", "Ilya", "EmailServiceUnitTest", "Demo", "Test",
            "<strong>Hello</strong>");

    Assert.Equal(1, test);
}
```

And the problem is that my mock does not rise my callback method

Probably the issue because of async nature of the method that mocks, but I really need some your help :)

Comment: please add `ISendGridClient`'s methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mocking

```
SendEmailAsync(new SendGridMessage(), CancellationToken.None)
```

But calling

```
_client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
```

So which one is the right one? Also you don't need this `test` variable. Simply use

```
 mockEmailClient.Verify(x => x.SendEmailAsync(...), Times.Once)
```

You could actually write it this way:

```
   public async Task EmailService_SendingEmail_EmailSentSuccessfullyAsync()
    {
        var mockEmailClient = new Mock<ISendGridClient>();

        mockEmailClient.Setup(x => x.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny<YourMessageType>()));

        var emailSender = new EmailService(mockEmailClient.Object);

        await emailSender.SendAsync("mail@gmail.com", "SenderDemo", "Ilya", "EmailServiceUnitTest", "Demo", "Test",
            "<strong>Hello</strong>");

        mockEmailClient.Verify(x => x.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny<YourMessageType>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

Comment: I need only "msg" without CancellationToken

Comment: Thanks! Yes, one needs to replace also the services having the mocked service injected...

Answer (score 2):

The mocked client needs to return a completed `Task` to allow the async flow to continue.

This will allow the call back to be invoked when the test is exercised.

```
public async Task EmailService_SendingEmail_EmailSentSuccessfullyAsync() {
    //Arrange
    var test = 0;

    var mockEmailClient = new Mock<ISendGridClient>();

    mockEmailClient
        .Setup(x => x.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny<SendGridMessage>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null)) //<-- needed to allow async flow to continue
        .Callback(() => test++);

    var emailSender = new EmailService(mockEmailClient.Object);

    //Act    
    await emailSender.SendAsync("mail@gmail.com", "SenderDemo", "Ilya", "EmailServiceUnitTest", "Demo", "Test",
            "<strong>Hello</strong>");

    //Assert    
    Assert.Equal(1, test);
}
```

Also note the changes to the test and the argument matchers used in setting up the mock